# I'm trying to map a list of products to a summarised list of products

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

The formula I'm using is IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Y$2,F2)),$Z$2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($Y$3,F2)),$Z$3,"No Match"))
The products are identified in column Y (from a longer list including duplicates in column F) and the name that I want to add to my new 'mapping' column is in column Z.

My formula works, but you can only add the ISNUMBER formula 64 times and I have 75 summarised products.  Is there a better formula that allows me to do this across a range of data rather than having to create this very long formula that doesn't even capture all the products!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simplified sample data including your desired results could go a long way here. See [ask] a question with an [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.